# Disable directory browsing apache isn't working

Tags: apache

I want to disable directory browsing in WordPress. But it's not working. 
Please help me. I've already edit htaccess (Options -Indexes)

This is folder httpd

```
   <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews


    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

   #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted


   </Directory>
  <Directory ${INSTALL_DIR}/www/wp-includes>
  Options -Indexes
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  </Directory>
```

Comment: Do you restart your httpd?

Comment: if I restart the apache? The answer is yes, i restart the server apache.

Answer (score 0):

There is some inconsistency in your config file.  I'm thinking that

```
<Directory ${INSTALL_DIR}/www/wp-includes>
```

Should actually be

```
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/wp-includes/">
```

Notice the missing **"** quotes and **/**

Also

```
AllowOverride all
```

should be

```
AllowOverride All
```

Notice the capital **A** on All

If that doesn't fix your problem let me know what version of Apache and is this Windows or Linux.